# Bind datasource which type is List<String> to dropdownlist which includes item template

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, telerik, rad-controls

here is my dropdownlist

```
 <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddDefaultValues" runat="server" DropDownWidth="100" Width="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="app-selectbox" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "String")%>' runat="server">
                </asp:Label>
                <telerik:RadButton runat="server" Text="-" Width="15" CssClass="button-delete" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false">
            </telerik:RadButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

and I bind data to my dropdown like that in code behind. I am using  "List< String >" as datasource

```
List<String>  liste = new List<String>();
liste.Add("-1");
liste.Add("-2");
ddDefaultValues.DataSource = liste;
ddDefaultValues.DataBind();
```

but  `Text='  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "String")%>'` didn't work I tried also  `Text='  <%#Container.DataItem%>'` but this way didn't work too.

How can I set dropdownlistitem's value to label's text ?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container.DataItem should work with such simple structures. It did for me:

```
     <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddDefaultValues" runat="server" DropDownWidth="100" Width="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="app-selectbox" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Container.DataItem%>' runat="server">
                </asp:Label>
                <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="-" Width="15" CssClass="button-delete" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false">
            </telerik:RadButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

and server code

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    List<String> liste = new List<String>();
    liste.Add("-1");
    liste.Add("-2");
    ddDefaultValues.DataSource = liste;
    ddDefaultValues.DataBind();
}
```

[image]